# trim left characters in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a sql statement to trim a string 'Hello' from the string "Hello World'.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select substring( field, 1, 5 ) from sometable
```

Comment: Mark, I need to trim the left 8 characters of a column from a table.Please suggest.

Comment: @Simhadri: In that case, as suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662496/trim-left-characters-in-sql-server/4662658#4662658), you could use `SELECT STUFF(field,1,8,'') FROM sometable`

Answer (score 25):

To *remove* the left-most word, you'll need to use either RIGHT or SUBSTRING. Assuming you know how many characters are involved, that would look either of the following:

```
SELECT RIGHT('Hello World', 5)
SELECT SUBSTRING('Hello World', 6, 100)
```

If you don't *know* how many characters that first word has, you'll need to find out using CHARINDEX, then substitute that value back into SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Hello World', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Hello World') + 1, 100)
```

This finds the position of the first space, then takes the remaining characters to the right.

Answer (score 9):

For 'Hello' at the start of the string:

```
SELECT STUFF('Hello World', 1, 6, '')
```

This will work for 'Hello' anywhere in the string:

```
SELECT REPLACE('Hello World', 'Hello ', '')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use LEN in combination with SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(myColumn, 7, LEN(myColumn)) from myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

use "LEFT"

```
 select left('Hello World', 5)
```

or use "SUBSTRING"

```
 select substring('Hello World', 1, 5)
```

Comment: Shane thanks for the reply, I need to disply World from Hello World.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to print only `Hello` right you can use this (works on command line client and workbench)

```
Select TRIM('World' from 'Hello World') as result;
```