# How to only show first 5 digits of a field in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trim left characters in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662496/trim-left-characters-in-sql-server)

I have a query below that grabs customer information from our database to send coupons.  In regards to the ZIP code, we only want the first 5 digits of the field... How can I return ONLY the first 5?  My code is below:

```
SELECT        Invoice_Tb.Customer_First_Name AS firstname, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Last_Name AS lastname, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address AS add1, Invoice_Tb.City, 
                         Invoice_Tb.Customer_State AS State, Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code AS ZIP, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Email_Address AS [Email Address], 
                         Invoice_Tb.Vehicle_Mileage AS [Vehicle Mileage], Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date AS [Date Of Service], Invoice_Tb.Store_Number, @startdate AS Start_Date, @enddate AS End_Date
FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb INNER JOIN
                         Invoice_Tb ON Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number = Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number AND Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date = Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date
WHERE        (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Category_Code = 'FS') AND (Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(Datetime, 
                         @enddate, 102)) AND (Invoice_Tb.Reminder_Mail_Flag = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
LEFT(FieldName, 5)
```

e.g.

```
SELECT LEFT(FieldName, 5) as SomeAlias FROM SomeTable
```

Table:

```
FieldName
---------
Hello World
```

Result:

```
SomeAlias
---------
Hello
```

Comment: Pefect!  Thanks.  I assume this means select the first 5 digits from the "Left"  If i Chose "Right" would it select the first 5 digits from the right?

Answer (score 0):

If your field is Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code, you can use the substring function:

```
substring(Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code, 1, 5) AS 'Trimmed Zip Code'
```

Another alternative is to use the LEFT function:

```
LEFT(Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code, 5) AS 'Trimmed Zip Code'
```

Since there is an implicit conversion from integers to nvarchar, and nvarchar equivalent, there is no need to worry about doing a CAST here.