# how to trim or remove specific characters from start of string

Tags: sql-server, trim

If I have codes stored in sql server database that look something like the following.

000001234560
000012345670
000000123450

How Can i remove all leading zeroes from the start of each code leaving me with

1234560
12345670
123450

Thank you

Comment: Just in start of string? or at ending too?

Comment: Its will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662496/trim-left-characters-in-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to numbers:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, YourColumn)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer through another stackoverflow query
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

The code that worked for me was

```
 SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: As your question is a duplicate of the other, don't post the answer from the other question here. there's no need as this question will be closed as a duplicate soon enough.