# Select Into Explanation / Temporary Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, temp-tables, select-into

Based on the tutorial on [SQL Temporary Tables](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZtYrELHP8M), it should be OK to create a temp table by using `SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM tableA` but it's throwing me `SQLException` when I trying to `SELECT * FROM #tempTable` saying that `Invalid object name '#tempTable'`. May I know what's the proper way of using a temp table in `C#`?

```
string sql = "SELECT * INTO ##tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    string sqlNew = "SELECT * FROM ##tempTable";
    using (var command2 = new SqlCommand(sqlNew, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["column1"].ToString());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My Objective is tryint to using the data retrieved from `sqlVar` and insert them into a tempTable and perform some operation on it. Very much appreciated if there is some sample code on how to fit the code into the above code. Thank You.

Comment: Temporary tables available during the session that creates them.

Comment: @HhamletHakobyan: I'm sorry that I couldn't figure out how to fix my problem with your description.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a temp table? what actions do you need to perform against the data? can you do this in the C# code?

Comment: @christiandev: I need to store them into a tempTable so that in my other method I can access the post-processed table again.

Comment: If you create a class with the fields you are going to work on, then you can use this for the processing and keep in memory until you're finished with it, and then store back to DB, or whatever you want to do with it.  It's difficult to be more sepcific without knowing what you need to do with the data.

Comment: @christiandev: I just want to know how temporary table works in C#. Please tell me how to create a tempTable in C# and just select data from them?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i think you answered his question.

Comment: Temp tables is a SQL specific concept.  So, within a stored procedure for example, you can store a subset of data in a temp table, work with that in the query and then, simple example here : http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage7.1/adssql/using_temporary_tables_in_sql_statements.htm

Comment: You're not executing the SQL code that selects in to the temporary table, so it is never created! See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But why you need temp table at SQL server side..

1) if you wish to perform operation on C# side just take data in `DATASET` instead of `DATAREADER` .. and

```
 DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
 {
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();                
     adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tableA", conn);
     conn.Open(); 
     adapter.Fill(dataset);
     conn.Close(); 
     foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0]) // Loop over the rows.
    {
        // perform your operation
    }
 }
```

2) if you need to perform operation on  SQL side then create a `stored procedure` at SQL server .. in the `stored procedure create #table` and use it ..

3) and you do not want to create `DATASET` then you can take data `LIST` and perform your operation on C# side

Comment: Why? 1. You can run plain SQL on the server side from within the C# script so that you can avoid having to deal with C# row-wise code. Then, there is no need to translate the SQL that you might have at hand into C# (or SSIS column types, if you are in SSIS). Instead, with temporary tables, you can run the plain SQL on top of the temporary table inside the C# script. You cannot do this with a dataset.

Comment: 2. For those working in SSIS: temporary tables can be taken as a source for the whole package, not just for the next item in the flow, and you can let the temp table grow over time while the package is alive. A side remark for SSIS: "Selecting into a temp table" in C# might seem easier than creating the tmpTable in a control flow as in [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196761/11154841). C# can do everything, but the control flow can already do this, perhaps you should stick to the SSIS defaults instead.

Answer (score 6):

You are not executing the first command at all, so the `SELECT INTO` isn't executed, so the temporary table is not created, so you get an error about the table not existing.

The code should read:

```
string sql = "SELECT * INTO ##tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <-- THIS

    string sqlNew = "SELECT * FROM ##tempTable";
    using (var command2 = new SqlCommand(sqlNew, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["column1"].ToString());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1-SELECT * INTO # tempTable FROM tableA (local temp)or
2-SELECT * INTO ## tempTable FROM tableA (global temp)then

Local temp tables are only available to the current connection for the user; and they are automatically deleted when the user disconnects from instances. Local temporary table name is stared with hash ("#") sign.

Global Temp Table

Global Temporary tables name starts with a double hash ("##"). Once this table has been created by a connection, like a permanent table it is then available to any user by any connection. It can only be deleted once all connections have been closed.

Both, Temporary tables are stored inside the Temporary Folder of tempdb. Whenever we create a temporary table, it goes to Temporary folder of tempdb database.

[temp table in SQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA8D4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change your temp table from `#tempTable` to `##tempTable`.

Using `##` means a global temp table that stays around. You'll need to Drop it after you have completed your task.

```
If Exists(Select * from tempdb..sysobjects Where id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable'))

DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Comment: It's still throwing me the same error. I've updated my question, please see if its the correct way that you've mentioned?

Comment: See my answer. You need to create a temporary table before you can use it!

Comment: Temporary tables get dropped after you stopped reading from them or if your SSIS run is over. I doubt that dropping the temp table is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in the comment:

**Temporary tables available during the session that creates them.**

If you want to actualy get the data you have to perform a SELECT statement from this temporary table **within the same scope**.

One more thing:

I don't see you are executing the `var command`, you are missing this line:

```
string sql = "SELECT * INTO ##tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();// This line is missing..
    string sqlNew = "SELECT * FROM ##tempTable";
    using (var command2 = new SqlCommand(sqlNew, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["column1"].ToString());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But missing the line isn't the reason why your implementation is wrong..

Comment: As I've said, I get an exception when I trying to select the temporary table with exception `Invalid object name '#tempTable'`. All operation are within the same scope

Comment: I thought I have `command2.ExecuteReader()`? Please show me how to do it, please

Comment: This is not the main part of my answer, you are doing something fundamentally wrong...