# Export temp table to excel in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, export-to-excel

Hi everyone I have small doubt in SSIS package:

I am using a stored procedure which is giving set of records, finally these records will be saved in temp table.

The thing is now I want this records to be exported to excel, so I planned to use **`SSIS`** package to do that. Now the problem is how will I define the OLE DB source in SSIS, because since am using `#temptable` at the runtime in stored procedure it will not be displayed in source of SSIS.

Kindly suggest to Export temp table to Excel files.

Comment: Did you do a search for your question? This question has been asked several times before.

Comment: searched but didnt get the exact answer, if so you can refer me the links, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That fact that you're using a temp table is not likely to matter too much. Is your temp table used in the stored procedure logic which outputs a select statement? If yes, then in your OLE DB source set Data Access Mode to SQL Command and call the store procedure (`EXEC myStoredProcedure`).

Using a `#temptable` can be problematic in SSIS. If you need to access a temp table in different data flows or transformations, then you will need to used the global `##temptable`.

Review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat), the answer goes into great detail on using temp tables.

Another Reference: [SSIS: Using temporary tables](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/11/19/SSIS_3A00_-Using-temporary-tables.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Execute SQL Task to execute the stored procedure, load the data into the temp table.

You can access the temp table with Query command instead of select from the drop-down list.

Remember set up the connection manager's property RetainSameConnection as TRUE