# temp table ssis using only Execute SQL Task

Tags: ssis, package, etl, temp-tables

I add my simple process

[image]

as you see at first Execute SQL Task  called "trae productos #prod"

this create and fill the temp table #prod

in the second Execute SQL Task  called "select temp" I use #prod for any thing
for example select, update, delete etc..
but this does not work I have change the property "RetainSameConection" to True and
all object have DelayValidation=True but this does not work, but this does work if I use a ##temptable and this does not work if I use a #Temptable, but I need to use a #Temptable

how can I get this work in other Execute SQL Task with 1 #.

this second image is inside a loop foreach before this loop i want to create my temptable

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you're splitting these up into two execute tasks when they should be one in the same. You can fill and select from a `#table` in the same Execute SQL task.

Comment: No but i need they are splitting because real problem in first Execute SQL task I create the #temp table and after i have a foreach and I use this #tempTable in the foreach and i could not created it every time because its takes much time for a loop

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? I'm not sure you are using these tools right.

Comment: I have 2 server A and B I create a #table from server A to B (products catalog) tables order and order_detail are in B, I concadenate a string as '1    2    3    ' and other '5    3    1' where first is product code and second is quantity(I use a scriptask for to concadenate) but just before it where i have a sql task wich return detail (after continue the foreach) i want to do a left join with thi stemp table for to know what product does not exist in server A, finnaly use a StoredProcedure which receive 2 String for save the order and detail

Comment: this second image is inside a loop foreach before this loop i want to create my temptable

Comment: Why not make this really easy and use a permanent table, not a temp table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat)