# SSIS failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN"

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, ssis

I'm trying to create a temp table and process two data flows using the temp table. It is in a sequence container and if I just execute the container it run perfect but when the entire package is ran it returns this error:

> Information: 0x4004300A at V-AccidentCodesBase, SSIS.Pipeline:
>   Validation phase is beginning.
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at V-AccidentCodesBase, Insert into Temp Table [69]:
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80040E14.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could
>   not be prepared.".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Invalid object name
>   '##TmpAccidentCode'.".
>
> Error: 0xC004706B at V-AccidentCodesBase, SSIS.Pipeline: "Insert into
>   Temp Table" failed validation and returned validation status
>   "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error: 0xC004700C at V-AccidentCodesBase, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more
>   component failed validation.
>
> Error: 0xC0024107 at V-AccidentCodesBase: There were errors during
>   task validation.

Comment: What does your job look like ?

Comment: So far I have fully declared the table to rule out it was finding the correct db and recreated the package due to reading that a change could corrupt the metadata.

Comment: And what happened when you used a user table instead of a temp table?

Comment: @epelletier9740 - I cannot read your mind. Please post more details. scrub off personal info before you post.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I am new to SSIS what do you mean by the job? Currently the process that the container does is creates a Temp table with a Execute SQL Task then it proceeds into a data flow that searches two columns in a source table and stores any duplicate rows into the temp table. JiggsJedi - I have just tried to store it in a user table and ran into the same issue with it running if just the sequence container is executed but not if the package is ran.

Comment: @epelletier9740 - My mistake. Sorry to confuse you. You can make 
SQL server run your package automatically. Then it becomes a "job". Anyway, you need to give more details. Btw, which version of SSIS are you using ?

Comment: If you're running into the same error using a user table, then we'll need to see your SSIS package (screen shots) so we can understand how you're creating the table, where its residing, and how you're inserting into it (show us the destination task).  This is a good test, as originally my thought was because # tables are non-persistent (unless you configure SSIS to maintain your connection for you).

Comment: The version of SSIS that im running is
Version 11.0.3369.0

Comment: @epelletier9740 - You mean SSIS 2012 ? I'll make a guess. There is not really much else I can do without seeing the package. Have you set "RetainSameConnection" = True for the connection manager which lets you connect to the server/instance (NOT DB, that would be tempDB) where the temp table is created  ?

Comment: Yes I am and I have set the RetainSameConnection = True. The temp table that i created was stored in tempDB. I am going to post some  a screen shot of the destination and how the temp table is created i can post any others if you would like.

Comment: It will not allow me to post screen shots due to not having 10 reputation points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem which was overloading tempDB. When I slowed the process down to one command to tempDb at a time it all ran through smoothly.

Answer (score 9):

I would set the DelayValidation property to True.  You may get away with just setting this on the Sequence Container, or you may need to repeat that setting on child objects, e.g. your Data Flow Task.

Answer (score 2):

Also faced the same error message.  The issue was permissions on the database for the user that runs the ETL (a service account).  Make sure the user that runs the package has enough permissions to execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

As other guys mentioned, the error may happen due to different reasons. In my case, I realized that I have tried to convert some NULL to int in Script section of SSIS. Something like :

```
ProductsBuffer.ProductId = Int64.Parse(reader["ProductId"].ToString());
```

so the fix was easy. I just checked the field before converting, to make sure it is not null:

```
 if (reader["ProductId"] != DBNull.Value)
            ProductsBuffer.ProductId = Int64.Parse(reader["ProductId"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I switched from OleDB to SQNCLI and it worked :/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, in my case, I was using SSIS to import data from an excel file into a couple of tables.

I used 2 differents files and it failed with one and worked with the other, after some review I found that I was referring to the name of the excel sheet within the package, so the excel sheet has to be named EXACTLY (i think it is case sensitive) as you used on the SSIS package

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2017.  I wonder if after a while it forgets your "saved" database passwords, because mine worked fine for days, then just quit working out of the blue, gave the `VS_ISBROKEN` error.  After I reentered the password for one of my database connections--despite the fact I had checked the `Save Password` checkbox previously--it started working again.