# Creating a temporary store with SSIS and use this in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'll try and keep this simple, I have one data-source (*DBX*) and one Source/Destination (*DBY*), both different servers.  I have read permissions on DBX, and Read/Write on DBY.  In SSMS, the workflow would look like this:

1. Get list of Id's from TblA in DBX..

   `SELECT Id INTO #IdTable FROM TblA WHERE....`
2. Get Data from TblB in DBX..

   `Select fields From TblB b join #IdTable a on b.Id = a.Id`

I will then save the data into DBY, so this part is straight forward.

The question is, whats the best way to create the temp table and join against it in an *SSIS DataFlow*?  I was looking at using a **DataReader Destination**, and I also looked at using **Recordset Destination**, but couldn't find an obvious way of doing this.

I have seen this solution of using temp tables [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat), but I'm not sure if the system account the package will run as will have permissions to create temp tables.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server security expert but I don't believe you can be restricted from creating temporary tables. That said, I don't believe this approach will work as the temporary table won't be able to jump server boundaries. Bigger picture, what are you trying to accomplish. Something like "For the given set of ids in Table A, I need to get the matches in table B. Each source id will exist, might exist once, might exist multiple times in table B"

Comment: I'm trying to substitute the *Temp Table* with a SSIS Control, and join against this.  It might not be a valid approach, but I thought I'd check before going down the temp table route.

Comment: I find the temporary table approach to be far too cantankerous to deal with myself which is why I was attempting to understand your problem better before offering alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following prototype will work.

[image]

**Steps:**

```
1. Create an SSIS package with a DFT
2. Add two connection managers to package, point them to 
    a. SourceServer.DBX.TblA and 
    b. DestinationServer.DBY.TblB
3. In the DFT create an OLEDB source (If not OLEDB, the type of your kind) with
    SELECT Id INTO #IdTable FROM TblA WHERE....
4. Add a LookUp Transformation after the source.
   In the genaral tab of lookUp Transformation, give DestinationServer.DBY.TblB
   In columns tab, give join column, (rest is self explainatory.)
5. You will get your desired output from LookUp Transformation output pipelines. 
   If required join the outputs together with a UnionAll transformation and point to your Destination.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - I will give it a try and get back to you.