# Use temporal table on SSIS using OLE DB source editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to execute SP who have temporal table and querys with 600 lines of code. So I insert SP code into variable and then I call OLEDB Source editor

temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TGJAE' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TGJAE 

SELECT
   VOUCHER,
   DATAAREAID,
   TAXITEMGROUP,
   TAXBASEAMOUNT,
   SOURCERECID
INTO ##TGJAE
FROM TAXTRANS
```

but when I try to save I get issue:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A Error at Flow [Query
>   [16]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement
>   'SELECT  VT.ACCOUNTNUM as [Código de Proveedor], "RFC" = CASE when
>   V.RFC_MX = '' then v.VATNUM else v' uses a temp table.".
>
> Error at Flow [Query [16]]: Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
>   database is available.

[image]

Any one know what happen there? Regards

Comment: Why a global temp? Why not just a local? I haven't tried, but I can only imagine using a global temp will cause some serious issues with SSIS.

Comment: I change it to local table and still getting same error @JacobH

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of a guess here, but you may need to explicitly define your temp table to pass the SSIS query validation.

Try using a full create statement instead of `SELECT... INTO`:

```
CREATE TABLE ##TGJAE (
     VOUCHER datatype,
     DATAAREAID datatype,
     TAXITEMGROUP datatype,
     TAXBASEAMOUNT datatype,
     SOURCERECID datatype);

INSERT INTO ##TGJAE
     SELECT VOUCHER,
            DATAAREAID,
            TAXITEMGROUP,
            TAXBASEAMOUNT,
            SOURCERECID
     FROM TAXTRANS
```

SSIS is finicky with metadata, and using `SELECT... INTO` to create a table means that SSIS doesn't know the metadata of the table columns until it is created.  ie. Metadata can't be determined.

Comment: I try it but I get invalid object name '##TGJAE'

Comment: @Ledwing I misunderstood the question and thought you had a temp table giving you trouble within a script, not a source component.  You could set up a retained connection, but you're going to have an easier time using a physical table.

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion here:

1. *temporal* tables and *temporary*  tables are completely different things. The `#` means you are using a temp table. It is highly unlikely that there are any performance improvements in using a temporary table, especially in this case where you have to load it first anyway!
2. The OLE DB source component needs to output a data set. The SQL you have written does not output a dataset at all which is why you get an error. Your SQL loads data into a *temporary* table but doesn't output data

Based on your example, you just need to change your code to this:

```
SELECT
   VOUCHER,
   DATAAREAID,
   TAXITEMGROUP,
   TAXBASEAMOUNT,
   SOURCERECID
FROM TAXTRANS;
```

Comment: But I use temporal table Into another selects, thats why I use it

Comment: We can't see those other selects on your question. I think you mean _temporary_

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is split this into two operations. Have your drop and create statement along with table population in a 'Execute SQL Task'. Use select statement in the DFT. Make sure 'Delay Validation' is set to true for your DFT in order to run. Also ensure you have a physical table created and not a global temp.

I would also advice against dropping every time and rather use a Truncate Statement.

Comment: What you mean with physical table? You mean local temporal table like #TGJAE?

Comment: No, I mean to say phyical table as in dbo.TGJAE.

Comment: Its more fast create table then truncate than create temporal table? Im doing temporal table to optimize query time

Comment: No, temp table does not give any added benefit. Having a physical table, you can do additional data manipulations over it and having it truncated before next run will ensure easier operations.  Moreover if you indeed need to use temp tables then there are additional settings that you need to take into account to address your issue. This link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat gives more info on that.