# Moving SSMS SQL scripts to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am in the process of moving some SQL scripts to SSIS. The premise of what the code does is it takes data from some source tables, creates some temporary tables along the way with some conditions and aggregations, and then joins the results together into a final output table.

I am trying to move my code to SSIS, but struggling a bit. In the data flow, I don't see any option to let me use some sort of script task. It seems I can only do it in the control flow, and I am unsure how to create these intermediary tables in control flow and then use them in the data flow. I would appreciate any pointers from anyone to get me going

```
USE MYDB;

IF OBJECT_ID('my_table') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE my_table;

SELECT 
       COL1,
       COL2,
       COL3policy_no
      ,SUM(COL4) as COL4_SUM
      ,MAX(COL5) as COL5_MAX

INTO temp_table
FROM my_table
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3;
```

I have attached a basic example of one of the temporary tables created as part of the original script

Comment: If you want to use a Script in the Data Flow you need to use a Script Component. If you don't have this this *strongly implies* you're using an unsupported version of SQL Server. Are you? But why would you want to create a temporary table in the middle of a Data Flow? This seems like a design flaw with the ETL process you have.

Comment: You will find your answer in the below link.

[How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DataFlow OLEDB Source you can use SQL Command and add your code*;

Using a stored procedure or a view is better ( use it in data flow as source).

Comment: Still stealing answers from [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3d1a09c-3882-4c47-8fca-f891874e9c38/moving-ssms-sql-scripts-to-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)