# How to add Temporary Table inside SSIS OLE DB Source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I want to get data from source using OLE DB.
used SQL command to get that.

I tried to set it with WITH clause. It worked. But it took **more time** to give the output.

```
WITH Temp
AS 
(
SELECT C.*
FROM DimCUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN DimSHOP S
ON C.CUST_ID = S.CUST_ID
)

SELECT *
FROM TEMP
WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
```

Then I tried it with **#** temporary table in SSMS.
it gave less time comparing to with clause.
SQL Code as Below.

```
SELECT C.*
    INTO #Temp
    FROM DimCUSTOMER C
    INNER JOIN DimSHOP S
    ON C.CUST_ID = S.CUST_ID
    
    SELECT *
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
```

Then I set this code inside SSIS package OLE DB Scource.
But I'm getting an error when setting the SQL Code inside it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably should just use a regular sql statement as the source, `select c.* from ... where c.address is not null` - what is the need of the cte or the temporary table?  Is it purely performance related?  Adding an index to the `address` field might resolve your issue.  If you have to do it, use a sql task to create it and then reference it in the data flow task.  Also make sure you have the `retainsameconnection` property of the connection set to `true`.   See this solution for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160015/1073631

Comment: Which version of sql server is the query being run against?

Answer (score 0):

First, use an Execute SQL Task into in the design view and rename it `Create Temp Table` :

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tmp
    CREATE TABLE ##tmp
    (
        //your columns
    )
INSERT INTO ##tmp
SELECT C.*
    FROM DimCUSTOMER C
    INNER JOIN DimSHOP S
    ON C.CUST_ID = S.CUST_ID
```

Once the table has been created into the SSIS package. Right click OLE DB Source and choose Edit. Choose your data source and choose SQL command for the Data access mode dropdown. In the SQL command text you will need to create our SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ##temp
    WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: So connection level temp table (##) is the solution.  As opposed to the # query level temp tables.
I have several temp tables so I assume this will work for that as well?