# SSIS running SQL Agent job with Creating temp table tasks

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm developing packages using multiple exec sql tasks objects that create temp tables, used later on data flow tasks.
Local executions of the package work, but I couldn't test this out in SQL Server.
Does running these create temp table tasks also run without issues when called from SQL Agent job?
Any recommendations in using temp tables in SSIS packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat). Personally I would steer away from trying to reuse temp tables at different points in the flow, because it depends upon a setting that more junior devs tend to be unaware of, and makes the logic fragile.

Comment: not really. i do not have experience with running ssis jobs from sql agent that use temp tables in the packages. that's the question. running them locally in VS works. i'm not sure if it fails when running from sql agent?

Comment: Per the linked question, the relevant property is "RetainSameConnection". You should not expect the temp tables to work unless this is set to true. If it is set to true, you should expect them to work. They *might* work if SSIS happens to reuse a connection even if this setting is false, but you cannot rely on that.