# Invalid expression term 'try'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

`PolicyPersonID` or `PolicyMemberID` will be a parameter in `GetInsuranceCompanyName()`. But `PolicyPersonID` or `PolicyMemberID` depends on the list of object bound to the grid view. If it's a list of policy members, `PolicyMemberID` will be there and `PolicyPersonID` won't be there, and vice versa.

I've tried an `if` statement but since it's either `PolicyPersonID` or `PolicyMemberID`, the `if` statement doesn't really work.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomerView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
            OnPageIndexChanging="gvCustomerView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# GetCustomerName(Eval("InvoiceMasterID")) %>' ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="MembershipNo" HeaderText="Membership Number" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insurance Company">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblInsuranceCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# try { GetInsuranceCompany(Eval("PolicyPersonID")); } catch (Exception) { GetInsuranceCompany(Eval("PolicyMemberID")); } %>' ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="PolicyNumber" HeaderText="Policy Number" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency Type And Rate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCurrencyTypeAndRate" runat="server" Text='<%# GetCurrencyTypeAndRate(Eval("InvoiceMasterID")) %>' ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone can explain what does the error mean with this:

```
Text='<%# try { GetInsuranceCompany(Eval("PolicyPersonID")); } catch (Exception) { GetInsuranceCompany(Eval("PolicyMemberID")); } %>'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not putting this code in a code behind?

Comment: I don’t think you can have try inside databinding, can you please try moving into your function GetInsuranceCompany..

Comment: @bestinamir I didnt really evaluate all the code but I dont think try/catch would work like the way the OP is doing it,.

Comment: the code behind has the logic for the method GetInsuranceCompanyName(). The insurance company is set depending on the PolicyMemberID or PolicyPersonID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<%#` token evaluates a *single expression*. It can't process try/catch blocks or other complex statements.

I would instead create a `GetInsuranceCompanyOrDefault` method (the name is up to you) in the code-behind that does this logic and call *that* method from the markup.

As a side note, throwing exceptions is an expensive way to do branching - if there is a way to know if `GetInsuranceCompany` will fail *before* calling the method that will be a cheaper way to determine which input to use.

Comment: Good point @DStanley. I did a post on this actually about the try catch vs if. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335217/try-catch-or-if-statement/17335269#17335269